# How can I get access to foreign_key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

There are

- a user-model/table,
- a schedule-model/table and
- a users_schedules-table.

The models has_and_belongs_to_many each other.
I can add a relationship with `@user.schedules << @schedule` in the controller.

How can I get access to the join-table 'users_schedules' ?

I want to show the users which has_and_belongs_to_many schedules:
I thought about something like this: `schedules.users_belongs_to`. As you can see in the view-code below.
**view:** (There is an example I want to add)

```
<table class="table table-hover">
        <tbody>
          <% @user_schedules_date.sort.each do |date_time, schedules| %>
            <tr class="thead success">
              <th colspan="4" scope="col"><p><%= date_time.strftime("%A, %d.%m.%Y") %></p></th>
            </tr>
            <% for schedule in schedules %>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row"><p><%= schedule.titel %></p></th>
 <td><p><%= schedules.users_belongs_to #ALL USERS WHO ARE BINDED TO THIS SCHEDULE# %></p></td>
                <td><p><%= schedule.date_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S") %></p></td>
                <td><p><%= schedule.location %></p></td>
                <td>
                  <p>
                    <%= link_to 'Bearbeiten', {:controller => 'schedule', :action => 'edit', :id => schedule.id} %>
                    oder
                    <%= link_to 'löschen', {:controller => 'schedule', :action => 'delete', :id => schedule.id} %>
                  </p>
                </td>
              </tr>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

In the controller I tried the following, but I don't know how to replace/fit the  placeholder `(:email)`.
**controller:**

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    if(current_user)
      @user_schedules = current_user.schedules
      @user_schedules_date = @user_schedules.order(:date_time).group_by { |sched| sched.date_time.beginning_of_day }
 @users_schedules_shared = User.find_by(:email) #HERE I NEED THE USER WHICH BELONGS_TO THIS SCHEDULE
    end
  end
end
```

I hope you can understand my problem.
**Thanks for your help!**

---

**EDIT:**
I gather all the data in the controller:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    if(current_user)
      @user_schedules = current_user.schedules
      @user_schedules_date = @user_schedules.order(:date_time).group_by { |sched| sched.date_time.beginning_of_day }
      @users_all = User.includes(user_schedules: :schedules)
    end
  end
end
```

and edit the view as the following:

```
<% @users_all.each do |user| %>
  <% user.name %>
<% end %>
```

But I get the following error:
`Association named 'user_schedules' was not found on User; perhaps you misspelled it?`

I red [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-a-single-object), as **deyan** said, but I dont understand it.

`@users_all = User.includes(user_schedules: :schedules)` <- returns an array ?!?? (If I understood it correctly)
So I need each array-item.name to show the Users name??

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

**Database:**
[image]https://i.stack.imgur.com/Apg7y.png

1. users
2. schedules_users (join-table with fk)
3. schedules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **I want to show the users which `has_and_belongs_to_many` schedules**

This will use something called a `many-to-many` relationship - meaning that if you access the associated data through a model - you'll have an appended attribute / method to capture them.

So what you'd do is the following:

```
#app/models/schedule.rb
Class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :schedules
end
```

This will append a `collection` to each of these model objects, allowing you to call the collection as required:

```
@schedules = Schedule.all
@schedules.each do |schedule|
   schedule.users #-> outputs a collection
   schedule.users.each do |user|
       user.name
   end
end
```

Using `includes` with Rails is actually quite a bad thing, considering you can call ActiveRecord associations to do the heavy-lifting for you

--

[**has_and_belongs_to_many**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)

Simply, you *can't* access the `has_and_belongs_to_many` table directly, as it has no [`primary_keys`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp) in place.

[image]

Rails basically uses the `relational database` infrastructure (through `ActiveRecord`) to access the associative data. This means that if you're using this particular type of table, you'll just be able to access the [`collection`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) it provisions:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :schedules
end

#app/models/schedule.rb
Class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

This will allow you to access:

```
@user = User.find 1
@user.schedules #-> shows schedules collection. You will have to loop through this
```

Comment: `schedule.users.each do |user|
 user.name
 end` That's what I needed! @Rich Peck: Thanks for all your help. Without your help I would be stranded!!

Comment: "Using includes with Rails is actually quite a bad thing" -- could you explain? Do you mean `Model.includes(:association)`?

Comment: Yes - just to clarify, I didn't mean using `includes` was always bad; I just meant that if you're using it in place of `associations` - which does the job for you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to show the schedules for your current user, and for each schedule to show what other users belong to it.

1. Based on your view, to get all users for a schedule, all you would need is to replace `schedules.users_belongs_to` with`schedule.users`.
2. If you want to get together all unique users for all the schedules the current user might have, then in the controller you could do `current_user.schedules.collect{|s| s.users|}.uniq`. This is only useful if you want to show all users, no matter which schedule each user belongs to.
3. I would advice you to gather all the data in the controller and then to print it in the view. You could join all tables in a single call to the DB, which might look something like this: `User.includes(users_schedules: :schedules)` but you would need to adapt it depending on what your models are called.

Methods 1 or 2 are solving your problem using your current code, but might be slow. I would suggest you read more here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html and get all data at once (method 3).

Comment: Yes you understand me correctly. Is that even so simple? :D I'll try it. How can I gather all the data in the controller?

Comment: Just edited the answer, hope that gives you more information. Using schedule.users will make a call to the DB for each schedule, so it's better to get everything in the controller and only use it in the view (without requesting the DB for new data).

Comment: Ok thanks. I try to understand it. Atm I use `schedules.users` and get the following output: `#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_User:0x44c6400>`. I thought I can use `schedules.users.name`, but then the output is: `User`. How can I get the users name ? There is a attribute `:name` in the User-model. I am confused now.

Comment: Firstly, you cannot use schedules.users because it doesn't know the users for which schedule you want to get. You can say schedules.first.users for example and then you will get a list of users for the first schedule. Secondly, you cannot say users.name for a similar reason. Ruby doesn't know which user's name you want. You can say users.first.name to test and see that it will give you the name of the first user. You can add .inspect if you want to see what is behind <ActiveRec.....>

Comment: About the error: "Association named 'user_schedules' was not found on User; perhaps you misspelled it?" I think for you it's called "users_schedules".

Comment: I dont get this Ruby-Logic: `@users_all = User.includes(user_schedules: :schedules)` works fine. `@users_all = User.includes(user_schedules: :schedules).INSPECT` even throws the error: `Association named 'user_schedules' was not found on User`

Comment: This drives me crazy. Why cant I even create a Join-SQL to get the users-name of the specific schedule..

Comment: @lsmoh, you have a model called UsersSchedule with all of its relationships, right?

Comment: I guess yes. I added the Database-Tables. Maybe it can help.

Comment: I don't know whether that make sense.. I dont have a SchedulesUsers-Model, because I thought I wouldnt need as the following link shows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25033822/need-help-to-understand-has-and-belongs-to-many

Comment: I thought I need something like this: `SELECT users.name FROM users WHERE users.id = schedules_users.user_id AND schedules.id = schedules_users.schedule_id`, but I dont know how to set this up in RubyOnRails.